What is the octern subgroup of M24?
In this post, "24 points" refers to the 24 points of the Golay code, or equivalently, the 24 points of the S(5,8,24) design.
Conjugacy classes of $M_{24}$ use the same names as in the ATLAS of Finite Groups; for example, 2A is the element of order 2 with the largest centralizer order, and 2B is the element of order 2 with the second largest centralizer order. The ATLAS indicates that the octern subgroup contains the following conjugacy classes:

2B, the order 2 element stabilizing a unique sextet but no points.
4C, the order 4 element consisting of 6 4-cycles, so squaring it gives a 2B element.
3A, the order 3 element stabilizing 6 points, which belong to a unique sextet.
7AB, the unique conjugacy classes of order 7, which are power equivalent.

According to the ATLAS, $M_{24}$ has an "octern" subgroup of type $L_2(7)$. It notes that the trio subgroup has an associated set of 8 triads such that 14 4-sets of these triads form dodecads, and an octern is a different orbit of 8 triads with this property. It gives no indication of how to actually find an octern, but it states that $L_2(7)$ acts transitively on 24 points and contains the conjugacy classes mentioned above. Note: It's possible that I am mistaken, and $L_2(7)$ acts transitively on 8 triads but not 24 points.
So, I am trying to figure out how to construct the octern subgroup. My approach is to fix a 7-cycle $b$ in $M_{24}$, a 3-cycle $t$ that normalizes $b$, and an involution $w$ that normalizes $t$, so that $\langle b,t,w\rangle$ is the octern subgroup (the names of these generators stand for Borel, torus, and Weyl, respectively). The normalizer of a 7-cycle in $M_{24}$ is $7\!:\!3\times S_3$, so a few 3-cycles normalize $b$, but only one of them belongs to conjguacy class $3A$, so we can easily determine $t$. The normalizer of $t$ is $3\cdot S_6$, so the 2B elements that normalize is are the synthemes. The only question left is which syntheme to choose. But we know that $b$ stabilizes a unique trio, so it stabilizes a unique syntheme $s$ in $3\cdot S_6$. Hence, we need only determine which syntheme is $w$:

If we choose $s$ itself, then $\langle b,t,w\rangle$ stabilizes the trio associated with $s$ (and all 3 octads belonging to that trio).
If we choose a syntheme that shares a duad with $s$, then $\langle b,t,w\rangle$ stabilizes one of the octads of the trio.

This leaves 8 synthemes, which do not share a duad with $s$. It is not hard to deduce that the $S_3$ group centralizing $\langle b,t\rangle$ divides these synthemes into orbits $O_1$ and $O_2$, which have lengths $2$ and $6$, respectively. It is also easy to see that if we choose $w$ from either orbit, then $\langle b,t,w\rangle$ does not stabilize any octads or trios. However, it would take a bit more effort to show that in one of these cases, $\langle b,t,w\rangle$ is a proper subgroup of $M_{24}$. Even so, this analysis already raises some anomalies:

The 7-cycle $b$ stabilizes a unique triad, which we will call $t_\infty$ and must be one of the triads in the octern.
The 3-cycle $t$ stabilizes 6 points, 3 of which belong to $t_\infty$, so the other 3 form another triad $t_0$.
The orbit of $t_0$ under $\langle a\rangle$ is the other 6 triads. However, these 8 triads belong to a trio, not an octern.

Given these anomalies, how do we construct the octern subgroup? I would be satisfied with either (or both) of the following, preferably in terms of the MOG:

Explicit generators for the octern subgroup (they could be the $b$, $t$, and $w$ that I described, or something else).
A list of triads that together form an octern.


An explicit octern is given in Conway and Sloane's book SPLAG (Sphere Packings, Lattices, and Groups), Chapter 11, Figure 11.31. All of the below is copied from there. In terms of the MOG (this follows the MOG conventions of SPLAG):
24 21 41 42 12 14
54 51 31 32 62 64
44 61 11 52 22 34
x4 01 x1 02 x2 04

Any 3 positions with the same first element (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,x) form a triad. Here x denotes $\infty$.
A set of generators of the octern group are
$\alpha^* : n_t \to (n+1)_t$
$\beta^*: n_t \to (2n)_{2t}$
$\gamma^*: n_t \to (-1/n)_{t/n^2 {\mbox{ or }} t^2}$
where all calculations are done mod 7, and the second option in $\gamma^*$ applies only in the cases $n=0$ and $n=\infty$.

Thanks, this helps a lot! It seems like the octern group actually contains conjugacy class 3B, so the ATLAS was inaccurate about the group containing 3A.
